# Mule: JMS Queue not response when Header: Content-Type is not compliant with JMS specification

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Currently am developing a proxy service REST to include guaranteed delivery in REST service operations (update, delete, insert) using JMS. Inside one of the flow I have:

```
<flow name="name" doc:name="name">
... 
<jms:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="**crear-cuenta-jms**" connector-ref="JMSConnector" doc:name="JMS" mimeType="application/json"/>
<logger message="payload is : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
....
</flow>
```

*** This flow receives json document and then sends it to a queue ***

In the flow queue listener:

```
<flow name="name2" doc:name="name2">        
<jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="JMSConnector" exchange-pattern="request-response" queue="**crear-cuenta-jms**" mimeType="application/json"/>
<set-payload value="Chevere" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

**when I run this flow generates a warning**

WARN  2014-09-17 11:07:49,379 [[dynamo-proxyrest-template.xml].responsableHTTPConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils: **Header: Content-Type is not compliant with JMS specification (sec. 3.5.1, 3.8.1.1)**. It will cause problems in your and other applications. Please update your application code to correct this. Mule renamed it to Content_Type

INFO  2014-09-17 11:07:50,524 [Dispatcher-Channel-2] org.mule.transport.jms.JmsReplyToHandler: Reply Message sent to: direct://amq.direct/TempQueueb4c14e85-7e1b-4e45-882f-531c09e0ec40/TempQueueb4c14e85-7e1b-4e45-882f-531c09e0ec40?routingkey='TempQueueb4c14e85-7e1b-4e45-882f-531c09e0ec40'&exclusive='true'&autodelete='true' with correlationID:ID:78836ef7-01f5-38c1-9612-76bae28fadc0

*** Here it can be observed which generates the appropriately the temporary queue ***

WARN  2014-09-17 11:07:50,532 [Dispatcher-Channel-2] org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils: Header: Content-Type is not compliant with JMS specification (sec. 3.5.1, 3.8.1.1). It will cause problems in your and other applications. Please update your application code to correct this. Mule renamed it to Content_Type

INFO  2014-09-17 11:07:59,790 [[dynamo-proxyrest-template.xml].responsableHTTPConnector.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: **payload post 3 es : {NullPayload}**

**in spite of this I can not retrieve the response message.**

I appreciate any help

Comment: Why do you put <set-payload value="Chevere" doc:name="Set Payload"/> before json:object-to-json-transformer ? .. It is replacing the payload  and it is in String format..

Comment: One more thing is what is the content type you are sending to JMS outbound ?? Is it a String , JSON, XML ??? Please share the full flow

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I resolved this error by removing the **MIME type** setting from my outbound JMS endpoint. Mule was automatically adding the **Content-Type** HTTP header because of this setting.